# Why do I get this error "Property 'fbAsyncInit' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."?

Tags: javascript, replit

I am writing my code in Replit. And it gives me the following error " **Property 'fbAsyncInit' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'** ". For this code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId   : '*************',
    cookie  : true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
    xfbml   : true, // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
    version : 'v13.0' // Use this Graph API version for this call.
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
    statusChangeCallback(response); // Returns the login status.
});

};
```

But when I run this code in my VS code it doesn't give me any error.

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using TypeSript in Replit ? It looks like a TS error to me. IMO you need to extend the window object with fbAsyncInit function fot TS compiler to get pass this error.

Comment: ``` declare global {
    interface Window {
        FB:any;
    }
}

let FB = window.FB ```

Comment: @LukeCelitan No, I don't have any ts file in replit.

Comment: Where should I declare the function you told me. @LukeCelitan

Comment: what template did you use ? Most of the time you put this in app.d.ts file

Comment: @LukeCelitan I have the code in main.js. But why doesn't it work in replit and works in vs code.